# How can I display the correct value?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5.2.7

My browser is Google Chrome  84.0.4147.89

Here's my program.

view

```
<form action="/Tabulations" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="condition1" name="condition1" value="@ViewBag.Condition1.ToString()" required />
        <input type="submit" formaction="dummy" value="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
<p>condition1=@ViewBag.Condition1.ToString()</p>
```

controller

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Controllers
{
    public class TabulationsController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult dummy(Nullable<int> condition1)
        {
            if (condition1.HasValue)
                ViewBag.Condition1 = condition1.Value;
            else
                ViewBag.Condition1 = 0;
            return View("dummy");
        }

    }
}
```

This is what the initial page looks like.

[image: initial page]

This is what it looks like when enter 1 and submit it.

[image]

When I click on the browser's back button, the initial page should be displayed.

The value shown in the `p` tag is back to 0. However, the value shown in the `input` tag is remains 1.

[image]

I look at the source of the page, the value in the `input` tag is 0.

[image]

Why is 1 displayed as the value of the `input` tag?

How can I display the correct value?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
CheckCondition();
$('#form').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
  CheckCondition();
});

$('#condition1').change(function(){
CheckCondition();
});
});

function CheckCondition(){
  var conditionText = $('#condition1').val();
    
    if(conditionText != null && conditionText != undefined && conditionText != "")
    {
        $('#condition').html("Condition 1 = " + conditionText);
    }
    else
    {$('#condition1').val(0);
       $('#condition').html("Condition 1 = " + 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/Tabulations" method="post" id="form">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="condition1" name="condition1" value="" required />
        <input type="submit" formaction="dummy" value="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
 <p id="condition"></p>
```

It is showing 1 because value is being changed at server side and you are just doing browser back which only executes client side code. You added code in form submit so, if you add code in ajax or in jquery ready function then it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm sorry for my poor explanation.
The mainly purpose is that "I want to display the value set on the server side as it is".
As you said, it is supposed to be rewritten by the script on the client side.
As far as I can see from the generated html, there is no place to load scripts, so I'm wondering why.
I'm sorry if it's a strange sentence because I'm not good at English.

Comment: Why there is no place to load script?

Comment: I posted a minimal program to reproduce the problem, but the actual program uses a model directive.
Umm, I can't explain well, so I will organize my questions and post again.
Thank you very much.